# How to fix "A suitable constructor for type '' could not be located" for Graph QL integration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, graphql

I am integrating `GraphQL` query using `Strawberry Shake` (to create client). I am using `HttpClient` to register it but getting following error:

> A suitable constructor for type 'Common.Clients.LocationGqlApi.LocationGqlApi' could not be located.

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong here?
- Is `Graph QL` integration different from REST APIs?

Program.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<ILocationGqlApi, LocationGqlApi>();
```

Service.cs:

```
namespace Returns.Services
{
    public interface ILocationService
    {
        public Task<bool> IsSchedulingLocation(string locationCode);
    }

    public class LocationService : ILocationService
    {
        private readonly ILocationGqlApi _locationGqlApi;
        
        public LocationService(ILocationGqlApi locationGqlApi)
        {
            _locationGqlApi = locationGqlApi;
        }

        public async Task<bool> IsSchedulingLocation(string locationCode)
        {
            var locationQlResponse = await _locationGqlApi.LocationByCode.ExecuteAsync(locationCode, LocationConstants.Capability);

           // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found the following solution:

Key Points:

- `.AddHttpClient` can be use for both `GraphQL` and `REST` endpoints.
- For `GraphQL`, Strawberry Shake generates the client which had `.AddLocationGqlApi`. So in my case, I had to add that after HTTP binding.

```
services.AddHttpClient(LocationGqlApi.ClientName, (serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.GetSettings("Services:Location:BaseUrl", "", false));
    options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
   
});
services.AddLocationGqlApi();
```